# IUPAC naming of purines and pyrimidines

Tags: nomenclature

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanine), the IUPAC name for *guanine* is **2-amino-1,9-dihydro-6*H*-purin-6-one** besides 2-amino-6-hydroxypurine and 2-aminohypoxanthine.

I have some difficulty understanding the **6*H*** part in its name since there's a keto group at the 6th position unlike in *cytosine* (4-aminopyrimidin-2(1*H*)-one) where the 1*H* clearly refers to the *hydrogen* at the 1st position

What does **6*H*** exactly mean?

[image]
[image]

Comment: So-called *Indicated* H https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/I03004

Comment: @Alchimista Thank you! But a thing still bugs me; the *indicated* hydrogen in cytosine gets added at position-1 which is also evident in its name. While in the case of guanine, it(hydrogen) apparently gets added at position-1 and *not* 6 as shown in its IUPAC name. Am I getting it right?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110664/bibenzimidazole-nomenclature-indicated-h-and-locants

Comment: @Nex the numbering fixes the double bonds with respect to purine numbering, guanine is named as a 1,9-dihydropurinone. The H in 1 isn't indicated H. See also Nilay Ghosh comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original parent structure purine ($\ce{C5H4N4}$) has the maximum number of noncumulative double bonds for this kind of structure. Compared to an ideal unsaturated compound, however, purine has one extra hydrogen somewhere. The position of this extra hydrogen must be indicated. A few different isomers are possible; for example, the original parent structure could be **9*H*-purine**.

[image: 9H-purine]

In the given compound, a double bond of the original purine is missing. Thus, the parent structure is a bit more saturated with the equivalent of two additional hydrogen atoms ($\ce{C5H6N4}$). Such saturation is described using ‘hydro’ prefixes. The locants of the original indicated hydrogen and the two additional hydrogens are 1, 6, and 9. The indicated hydrogen gets the lowest locant, so the name of the unsubstituted parent structure is **6,9-dihydro-1*H*-purine.**

[image: 6,9-dihydro-1H-purine]

In the substituted purin-6-one, however, the numbering is different because a double bond was removed to make room for the ketone. According to Rule P-58.2.3, the indicated hydrogen is placed at the position that will accommodate this principal characteristic group. Therefore, the name becomes **1,9-dihydro-6*H*-purin-6-one.**

[image: 1,9-dihydro-6H-purin-6-one]

Comment: Am I right in thinking that there is no hydrogen at or near position six? If so, could someone add to the answer an acknowledgement of this and an explanation of what exactly is meant by "indicated hydrogen"? Is it in fact not a hydrogen atom at all, but a configuration of bonds?

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh [IUPAC Gold Book: indicated hydrogen](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.I03004)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already read it after seeing it in Alchemista's comment. There is a slight problem with it, however. In all the examples given in the link there is an actual hydrogen atom at the position referred to. There is no example analogous to the "6H" of 2-amino-1,9-dihydro-6H-purin-6-one where, if I am correct, there is *no* actual hydrogen atom at position 6. The nearest hydrogen being attached to the nitrogen at position 5. Could someone please confirm that the nearest H to position 6 is attached to N5?

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh In the final product 2-amino-1,9-dihydro-6H-purin-6-one, three hydrogen atoms of 6,9-dihydro-1H-purine are substituted with other groups. So, _yes,_ there is no hydrogen atom left at position 6. However, _no,_ there is no hydrogen attached to position 5 and there is no nitrogen at position 5.

Comment: I meant to ask, "Could someone please confirm that the nearest H to position 6 is attached to N1?" You are right that there is no N5. I got confused about the numbering; my diagram has no numbering and left and right are reversed and I confused left and right I think. Thanks for confirming that there is no hydrogen at position 6. It sounds like "6H" refers to a hydrogen atom in a molecule that could be a precursor in a chemical process that synthesizes 2-amino-1,9-dihydro-6H-purin-6-one or perhaps in a "parent" molecule in a taxonomy of molecules. I find it very hard to understand.