# Purpose of "1H" in naming of substituted heterocyclic compouns

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, aromatic-compounds, heterocyclic-compounds, organoboron-compounds

I had a curious thought about the following molecule's name:

[image: heterocyclic compound and its name]

For such a simple molecule it seemed awfully complicated.  From what I gathered, the "[c][1,2]oxaborinin-1-ol" stems from the following fragment:

[image: substructure and its name]

whereby [c] indicates the bond of fusion between the trifluoromethylbenzene and 1,2-oxaboran-2-ol.

The "7-(trifluoromethyl)-3,4-dihydro" is pretty evident from the compound's IUPAC numbering, where the heteroatoms are given the lowest numbers. However, from what I understand, the "1H" designation should to the location of unsaturation (similar to the saturation at carbons 3 & 4), but this boron has no hydrogen.

[image: the compound with its locants]

I'm clearly missing some fundamental nomenclature insight.  Could anyone please help shed some light on this?

Comment: See, the parent structure used in the name is unsaturated borinine not saturated borinan - it doesn't have the 1H hydrogen that's substituted with -OH in your structure.

Comment: and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/160333/iupac-naming-of-purines-and-pyrimidines?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Mithoron Ah, I see.  So when naming these fused ring systems, is the parent structure always the aromatic compound?